# How can I pick a good magic/type number for ioctl?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I was wondering if there was a macro that could assign my device a random 'magic' number that linux was currently not using. This is obviously in the interest of portability. Also if this is not possible, I would like to know where I can find out which magic numbers are not used. The text file I want to consult I believe is called ioctl-number.txt, but I could only find those files in the source tree I downloaded ... not the compiled kernel that I actually run. It would be interesting to find where those files may hide in the compiled version.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's an [article](http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x892.html) that brings interesting info on this subject.

Comment: Could you handle your problem ? Because I also do not know how to pick up good magic number from that table.

Answer (score 2):

Could you select an existing ioctl macro that your device driver does not (and will never) use, and assign its value to a macro for the ioctl you require?

I have a limited knowledge of how ioclt works with device drivers, so maybe this doesn't work.

Can you look at the source for another device driver that has custom ioctl values, and see how they've selected their numbers?  Maybe there's a range that the OS doesn't use, so they're available for each device driver to interpret however it wishes.

Comment: I'm trying to make an unused cmd number so that ioctl knows which io operation to do on what dev. The cmd number is not a macro but a number that must remain unique accross the entire system. No other device may use another cmd number that is the same as the a cmd number that my device uses. Its like allocating device numbers for you device to use, except there are no macros that I know of that finds a random 'magic' number. This magic number corresponds to the device itself, yet somehow it is still different to the device number. How do I find unused magic #s?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when talking about the magic number, we are referring to 8-bit "type" in the following built-in IO calls

```c
#define _IO(type,nr)        _IOC(_IOC_NONE,(type),(nr),0)
#define _IOR(type,nr,size)  _IOC(_IOC_READ,(type),(nr),(_IOC_TYPECHECK(size)))
#define _IOW(type,nr,size)  _IOC(_IOC_WRITE,(type),(nr),(_IOC_TYPECHECK(size)))
#define _IOWR(type,nr,size) _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE,(type),(nr),(_IOC_TYPECHECK(size)))
```

From what I'm seeing so far, there doesn't seem to be a way to dynamically assign this value. Like you mentioned, it is recommended we look at the [ioctl-number.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/ioctl/ioctl-number.html)  document for an open number and use it. To "ensure" another device doesn't use it in the future, we should push up our changes and register our magic number to be added to the list. From that document:

> If you are writing a driver for a new device and need a letter, pick an
> unused block with enough room for expansion: 32 to 256 ioctl commands.
> You can register the block by patching this file and submitting the
> patch to Linus Torvalds.  Or you can e-mail me at mec@shout.net and
> I'll register one for you.

That seems a bit cumbersome and error-prone. And with a vast community, those 8 bits could be filled quite quickly.